# OB Fees Request with Amadeus Fare_PricePnrWithBookingClass

Tags: c#, xml, request, amadeus

Have been stuck for quite a while, anyone please help me to send the OB Fees (Airline Fees) and amount  with the Fare_PricePnrWithBookingClass request.
Here’s the XML request:

```
<Fare_PricePNRWithBookingClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/TPCBRQ_16_1_1A">
<pricingOptionGroup xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/TPCBRQ_16_1_1A">
<pricingOptionKey><pricingOptionKey>RW</pricingOptionKey>
</pricingOptionKey>
<optionDetail>
<criteriaDetails><attributeType>GOVSR123</attributeType>
</criteriaDetails>
</optionDetail></pricingOptionGroup><pricingOptionGroup xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/TPCBRQ_16_1_1A">
<pricingOptionKey>
<pricingOptionKey>FCO</pricingOptionKey>
</pricingOptionKey>
<currency>
<firstCurrencyDetails><currencyQualifier>FCO</currencyQualifier>
<currencyIsoCode>SAR</currencyIsoCode>
</firstCurrencyDetails>
</currency>
</pricingOptionGroup>
</Fare_PricePNRWithBookingClass>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Since you're a new contributor, here's some feedback. It's impossible to even guess at this, because we don't know what you are trying to do, or anything about the context. Are you sending this request? If so, how? What language and platform, ie. browser, server?  Is there any documentation?

Comment: Hi Ben,I want to send the OB fees (airline ticketing fees) along with this xml request, Amadeus documentation says we can send the OB fees with this request but doesn’t say which tags. I want someone who has worked with Amadeus web services to add the tags were OB fees and amount can be added. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> pricingOptionGroups = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "pricingOptionGroup").ToList();
            XNamespace ns = pricingOptionGroups.First().GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<PricingOptionGroup> groups = pricingOptionGroups.Select(x => new PricingOptionGroup()
            {
                key = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "pricingOptionKey").FirstOrDefault(),
                attributeType = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "attributeType").FirstOrDefault(),
                currencyQualifier = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "currencyQualifier").FirstOrDefault(),
                currencyIsoCode = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "currencyIsoCode").FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();


        }
    }
    public class PricingOptionGroup
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string attributeType { get; set; }
        public string currencyQualifier { get; set; }
        public string currencyIsoCode { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `<pricingOptionKey>OBF</pricingOptionKey>` to include or exclude your OB fees.

To make `TST 1` updated with additional OB fee sub-code `OT1` of 50 USD you may try something like follows:

```xml
            <ns1:pricingOptionGroup>
                <ns1:pricingOptionKey>
                    <ns1:pricingOptionKey>OBF</ns1:pricingOptionKey>
                </ns1:pricingOptionKey>
                <ns1:penDisInformation>
                    <ns1:discountPenaltyQualifier>OBF</ns1:discountPenaltyQualifier>
                    <ns1:discountPenaltyDetails>
                        <ns1:function>INF</ns1:function>
                        <ns1:amountType>707</ns1:amountType>
                        <ns1:amount>50</ns1:amount>
                        <ns1:rate>OT1</ns1:rate>
                        <ns1:currency>USD</ns1:currency>
                    </ns1:discountPenaltyDetails>
                </ns1:penDisInformation>
                <ns1:paxSegTstReference>
                    <ns1:referenceDetails>
                        <ns1:type>P</ns1:type>
                        <ns1:value>1</ns1:value>
                    </ns1:referenceDetails>
                </ns1:paxSegTstReference>
            </ns1:pricingOptionGroup>
```

where `INF` stands for inclusion, and `707` means that you use fixed amount, `paxSegTstReference` is for referencing a TST record.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, Please can you send me an XML example of OB fees with 50.00 USD, commercial name "FEE"  and subcode "OT1"

Comment: Hi, please find an updated answer with an example. Did not have a chance to check it myself though, as I dont have an access to the Amadeus endpoints anymore.

Comment: Hi Christina, 
Thanks for your reply, 
I am getting this error "CHECK FORMAT"

Comment: Are there any details to the error? Are you sure about the subcode value?

Comment: Error has only "CHECK FORMAT", PNR created in native mode in the same office ID adds airline fee perfectly. 
here's the DisplayTST for PNR created by the agent in native mode, XML added in the comment below because of the No. of characters restriction.
Thanks

Comment: <carrierFeesGroup>
<carrierFeeType>
<selectionDetails>
<option>OB</option>
</selectionDetails>
</carrierFeeType>
<carrierFeeInfo>
<carrierFeeSubcode>
<dataTypeInformation>
<type>OT1</type>
</dataTypeInformation>
</carrierFeeSubcode>
<commercialName>
<freeTextQualification>
<textSubjectQualifier>COM</textSubjectQualifier>
</freeTextQualification>
<freeText>FEE</freeText>
</commercialName>
<feeAmount>
<monetaryDetails>
<typeQualifier>TIN</typeQualifier>
<amount>50.00</amount>
<currency>USD</currency>
</monetaryDetails></feeAmount>
</carrierFeeInfo>
</carrierFeesGroup>